# Error resolving template ***, template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have spring boot + thymeleaf project, if I run project on the Intellij Idea, there is no problem, but When I run jar file, I faced this problem.
This is error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/login], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

[This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9uyJ.jpg)jpg

Comment: And without some code, configuration you expect us to magically know what is wrong? Please also don't post errors as code but as plain text using proper formatting as now we need to click and if we are unlucky it is an unreadable image we are linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be easier with some code, but here is a working example with spring boot and Maven.

I have a template called "myTemplate.html" in the folder src/main/resources/templates.

In one of my class I have :

```
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
Context context = new Context();
//... then here i fill all the variables used in my template

String filledTemplate = templateEngine.process("templates/myTemplate", context);
```

And everything works as expected

Hope it helps a bit :)